# Javascript ternary user error?

Tags: javascript, ternary

So what I'm trying to do is make a script that will show and hide the title of YouTube videos and all my script seems to be doing is setting it default to display none which I don't want it to do that and it seems as if the onclick function isn't even working either. I honestly cannot figure out what I did wrong... everything seems like it should work.

Here's the script:

```
function titleToggle() {
    eowTitle = document.getElementById('eow-title');
    watch7Headline = document.getElementById('watch7-headline');
    eowTitle.style.display = 'inline-block';
    (eowTitle.style.display == 'none') ? watch7Headline.onclick = eowTitle.style.display = 'inline-block' : watch7Headline.onclick = eowTitle.style.display = 'none';
}
titleToggle();
```

Comment: It seems you have trouble with operator precedence. Namely check the priority of `=` vs. `?:`

Comment: Why are assigning `'inline-block'` and then checking if it is `== 'none'`?

Comment: Your problem description isn't very clear. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: When they click the watch7-headline element it should hide or show the eow-title based on the current display of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "onclick" property to a **function**. If you really want to use `? :`, you'd be better off doing this:

```
watch7Headline.onclick = function() {
  eowTitle.style.display = (eowTitle.style.display == 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked. I never thought of doing eowTitle.style.display = (then the ternary statement) to condense it.. I'll keep this in mind next time.

Comment: @Bren , actually, the way you were doing would also raise an error in jshint (you should be assigning the ternary operator's result to a variable)